# I have problem with decryption with php and mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, openssl, base64

I have problem whit this line of code echo  . $den .  In the table in the "row - day" I don't have data. I use PHP 7.4.10 Please answer me where is the problem. Whether the problem is for that I use function novadata but when i used them for only one string there is not problems.

```
function novadata($novadata) {
$specificDate = strtotime('2020-9-25');
// Using DateTime Object
$yourDate = "$novadata-12-25";
$yourDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $yourDate);
$mydate = $yourDate->format("l");
return $mydate;
}

$key = "fhaskdhflkjshskfhakjsfhk";

function encryptthis($data, $key) {
    $encryption_key = base64_decode($key);
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-cbc'));
    $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, 'aes-256-cbc', $encryption_key,0,$iv);
    return base64_encode($encrypted . '::' . $iv);
}

function decryptthis($data,$key) {
    $encryption_key = base64_decode($key);
    list($encrypted_data, $iv) = array_pad(explode('::', base64_decode($data),2),2, null);
    return openssl_decrypt($encrypted_data, 'aes-256-cbc', $encryption_key,0,$iv);
}
    $var = novadata($year);
    $enc = encryptthis($var, $key);

    $dec = decryptthis($enc, $key);

mysqli_select_db($con,"primenumber");
$result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM prime2");

echo "<table style='border:1px solid black; align:center' >
<tr>
<td style='text-align:center; border:1px solid black;'> <b>Reden Br.</b></td>
<td style='text-align:center; border:1px solid black;'><b>Godina</b></td>
<td style='text-align:center; border:1px solid black;'><b>Den</b></td>";

while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{   
    $id = $data['id'];
    $year = $data['year'];
    $den = decryptthis($data['day'], $key);

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td style='text-align:center; border:1px solid black;'>" . $id  . "</td>";
    echo "<td style='text-align:center; border:1px solid black;'>" . $year . "</td>";
    echo "<td style='text-align:center; border:1px solid black;'>" . $den . ""</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Can you more clearly explain what your code should do and how its currently failing? At the moment its difficult to understand what you're asking.

Comment: Please provide more details on data base tables

Comment: Now it turn me the problem...                    Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\opa\functions.php:27 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\opa\functions.php(35): novadata('1931') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\opa\functions.php on line 27               It's say that the problem is in the formated datetime. This line $mydate = $yourDate->format("l");

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if there is some data in your mysql-field 'day'?

Below you find a simplified version of your code that just uses the novadata and en-/decryption functions. As you can see the complete program is running perfectly so I believe that your mysql-data is missing. You can simply check this by leaving out the decryption-part:

```
$den = decryptthis($data['day'], $key);
change to
$den = $data['day'];
```

You should read something like:

```
dUpHVG5mZ3Vwcy8rUnBhSHJLZUhTdz09Ojr5shbj48lpWxc8inMNnIg1
```

**Security warning**: this code uses a static key that is **UNSECURE**.

My code:

```
<?php
function novadata($novadata) {
    $specificDate = strtotime('2020-9-25');
    // Using DateTime Object
    $yourDate = "$novadata-12-25";
    $yourDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $yourDate);
    $mydate = $yourDate->format("l");
    return $mydate;
}

$key = "fhaskdhflkjshskfhakjsfhk";

function encryptthis($data, $key) {
    $encryption_key = base64_decode($key);
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-cbc'));
    $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, 'aes-256-cbc', $encryption_key,0,$iv);
    return base64_encode($encrypted . '::' . $iv);
}

function decryptthis($data,$key) {
    $encryption_key = base64_decode($key);
    list($encrypted_data, $iv) = array_pad(explode('::', base64_decode($data),2),2, null);
    return openssl_decrypt($encrypted_data, 'aes-256-cbc', $encryption_key,0,$iv);
}
$year = 2025;
$var = novadata($year);
echo 'var: ' . $var . PHP_EOL;
$enc = encryptthis($var, $key);
echo 'enc: ' . $enc . PHP_EOL;
$dec = decryptthis($enc, $key);
echo 'dec: ' . $dec . PHP_EOL;

?>
```

output:

```
var: Thursday
enc: dUpHVG5mZ3Vwcy8rUnBhSHJLZUhTdz09Ojr5shbj48lpWxc8inMNnIg1
dec: Thursday
```

Comment: And where I test like this, there is no problem, but when i send to the database also there aren't problems, the day is encrypted, but i don't have return from the database... Now it turn me the problem...                    Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\opa\functions.php:27 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\opa\functions.php(35): novadata('1931') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\opa\functions.php on line 27               It's say that the problem is in the formated datetime. This line:  $mydate = $yourDate->format("l");

Comment: So there is NO problem with encryption/decryption but with data send to or getting from sql DB. Did you keep in mind that the encrypted date is no longer a date format but a longer string?